# get-pnpweb example with connection parameter

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Does anyone have an example of Get-pnpweb with connection parameter please? I'm trying to get to a different web in my script and I believe the only way to achieve this is using this parameter, but I can't seem to find an example.

Thanks
Ova

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connection needs to be returned from PnP command when you connect to a site/web
you can implement this as below.

```
#Web 1 already connected
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/web1"  -Credentials $creds -ReturnConnection

#Connecting Web2 with connection
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/web2"  -Credentials $creds -ReturnConnection

#get Web2 using connection
$webs = Get-PnPWeb -Connection $connection
```

Comment: I need to connect 2 other webs(web2 and web3)  in my script to add group of web1 to them, just thinking if it's best practice to throw so many connections around?

Comment: You can dispose the connection after done with it using Disconnect-PnPOnline -Connection $connection

Answer (score 2):

While I think this works, you might want to look into Set-PnPContext that I've added later in my answer.

```
$connectionA = Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://siteA.com -CurrentCredentials -ReturnConnection

$connectionB = Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://siteB.com -CurrentCredentials -ReturnConnection

Get-PnPWeb -Connection $connectionA
Get-PnPWeb -Connection $connectionB
```

[Set-PnPContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpcontext?view=sharepoint-ps)

> **Description**
>
> Sets the Client Context to use by the cmdlets, which allows easy
> context switching. See examples for details.
>
> ```
> Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteAurl -Credentials $credentials
> $ctx = Get-PnPContext
> Get-PnPList # returns the lists from site specified with $siteAurl
> Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteBurl -Credentials $credentials
> Get-PnPList # returns the lists from the site specified with $siteBurl
> Set-PnPContext -Context $ctx # switch back to site A
> Get-PnPList # returns the lists from site A
> ```

Comment: do you know if the command closes the connection after being used as in the first example?

$web2= Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $Cred
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $owners -AddRole "Read" -connection $web2

I need to run something like this and wondering if it will close the connection automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Many/most/all PnP SharePoint cmdlets do seem to require that the web you're working with match the one last referenced in the call to Connect-PnPOnline. Making two Connect calls and assigning each to a var does not seem to work for context switching between webs. Explicitly setting the Connection parameter in a call may still be a good idea to help trigger an error when a connection isn't available - the cmdlet does then seem to always return a null and the cmdlet will fail.

Hope this helps!
-e.